# How to conditionally hide a field based on another fields value WITHOUT focus in Acrobat PDF?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a Acrobat form in which items in a list are added up, and once added to together, if the value exceeds 5000, then a form field with a white background should be UNHIDDEN so that the form displays an alert that will be printed. (I'm not sure I'm able to conditionally show just plain text - which is why I did this).

This is the javascript I pieced together to try to hide the field, and it works - but since the field that this is based on is a calculation field, nobody will ever focus on it unless they tab through the entire form (which won't work well). How do I make this calculate regardless of user focus? Or can I base the focus on another field without regard to the 'properties' window?

```
if (event.target.value > "4999.99") }
   this.getField("ifOver5000").display = display.hidden;
)
else {
   this.getField("ifOver5000".display = display.visible;
}
```

`ifOver5000` is the field that hides the text on the form (the notification).

`event.target.value` refers to the calculation field that adds everything together (the field upon which the valdiation should be performed).

Comment: why are you comparing a number as a string?

Comment: So onchange of any field trigger the validation code.

Comment: Is this value a length or a score?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple points that you have to change to get it working:

First, it seems that you're trying to use a `style` property of a DOM object:

```js
// from
this.getField("ifOver5000".display = display.visible;
// to
this.getField("ifOver5000").style.display = 'visible';
```

Second, I'm not sure what `getField` method returns -- it seems that it comes from a third-party library. Be sure to check that it returns a DOM object or read documentation of that library, because there is a great chance that it may have some specific solution.

Here is a working version:

```js
document.getElementById('inputTarget').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (parseFloat(event.target.value) > 4999.99) {
    document.getElementById('ifOver5000').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ifOver5000').style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="inputTarget" value="1900">
<p id="ifOver5000">This should hide if you enter more than 5000 or more</p>
```